# Unity compute shader debug using RenderDoc not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, hlsl, compute-shader, renderdoc

I'm trying to debug a compute shader using RenderDoc with Unity.

Currently, my "debug" option is greyed out:

[image: Greyed out "Debug" symbol]

I've had a look around and came across this forum post which leads to nowhere:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/compute-shader-debug-symbols-w-renderdoc.398214/

It suggests that I need some way of disabling optimisation with some pragma but that pragma doesn't seem to exist. How can I debug this compute shader with Unity / RenderDoc? Surely it's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I needed to select the dispatch I wanted to debug:
[image]