# Trying to view source code for a Houdini file

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, houdini

I want to better understand a remarkable paper:
[https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~alchern/projects/MinimalCurrent/](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ealchern/projects/MinimalCurrent/)

The authors provide the source code as a proprietary binary code that can only be opened in Houdini. A `.hipnc` file. The binary data can be viewed in other applications, but not the source code.

Opening the file with the free licensed version of Houdini shows some graphical output.

[image]

However searching around in the documentation and playing with the UI I cannot find a text editor to actually see the source code of what the researchers were doing.

Given the original paper description, I know that the source code is contained in the Houdini file. The authors explicitly say so. But I cannot find documentation describing how to see that source code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have edited my answer to expand a little bit more. However, 

"and what you've done, what code you wrote, what running that did that you didn't expect,"

This question is identical in nature to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code

It is asking how to use an existing software tool to view and compile source code. Not all programming questions that belong in SO require the asker to write code.

Comment: Consider this question about renderdoc as an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70513055/unity-compute-shader-debug-using-renderdoc-not-working

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423414/2821954).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Houdini is described as an "IDE for computer graphics", and not a typical code/script editor. In the context of this question, the `.hipnc` file contains a workflow comprising network nodes, which looks something like below in `Network View`:

[image]

Assuming you are interested in the `mincurr_FFT_solver` node, you can use the built-in `Python Shell` to get the source code of any given node:

```py
import hou
node = hou.node('/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver')
print(node.asCode())
```

Results when written to file:

```py
# Initialize parent node variable.
if locals().get("hou_parent") is None:
    hou_parent = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current")

# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver
hou_node = hou_parent.createNode("subnet", "mincurr_FFT_solver", run_init_scripts=False, load_contents=True, exact_type_name=True)
hou_node.move(hou.Vector2(1.25615, -5.79144))
hou_node.bypass(False)
hou_node.setDisplayFlag(False)
hou_node.hide(False)
hou_node.setHighlightFlag(False)
hou_node.setHardLocked(False)
hou_node.setSoftLocked(False)
hou_node.setSelectableTemplateFlag(False)
hou_node.setSelected(True)
hou_node.setRenderFlag(False)
hou_node.setTemplateFlag(False)
hou_node.setUnloadFlag(False)

hou_parm_template_group = hou.ParmTemplateGroup()
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.StringParmTemplate("label1", "Input #1 Label", 1, default_value=(["Sub-Network Input #1"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.Regular, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.StringParmTemplate("label2", "Input #2 Label", 1, default_value=(["Sub-Network Input #2"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.Regular, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.StringParmTemplate("label3", "Input #3 Label", 1, default_value=(["Sub-Network Input #3"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.Regular, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.StringParmTemplate("label4", "Input #4 Label", 1, default_value=(["Sub-Network Input #4"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.Regular, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.ButtonParmTemplate("resimulate", "Reset Simulation")
hou_parm_template.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000"})
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.FolderParmTemplate("folder0", "Fast ADMM Parameters", folder_type=hou.folderType.Simple, default_value=0, ends_tab_group=False)
hou_parm_template.setTags({"group_type": "simple"})
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.FloatParmTemplate("tau", "time step (tau)", 1, default_value=([0.1]), min=0, max=1, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.FloatParmTemplate("c_threshold", "threshold (c_threshold)", 1, default_value=([0.5]), min=0, max=1, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.FolderParmTemplate("folder1", "Pointers to Volumes", folder_type=hou.folderType.Simple, default_value=0, ends_tab_group=False)
hou_parm_template.setTags({"group_type": "simple"})
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("rhs", "RHS", 1, default_value=([32]), min=0, max=10, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_eta0", "eta0", 1, default_value=([2]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_eta", "eta", 1, default_value=([5]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_phi", "phi", 1, default_value=([9]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_X", "X", 1, default_value=([10]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_Xhat", "Xhat", 1, default_value=([13]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_Xprev", "Xprev", 1, default_value=([16]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_lambda", "lambda", 1, default_value=([19]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_lambdahat", "lambdahat", 1, default_value=([22]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_lambdaprev", "lambdaprev", 1, default_value=([25]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_Y", "Y", 1, default_value=([28]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.IntParmTemplate("ind_summand", "summand", 1, default_value=([31]), min=0, max=30, min_is_strict=False, max_is_strict=False, look=hou.parmLook.Regular, naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal, menu_use_token=False)
hou_parm_template2.setScriptCallbackLanguage(hou.scriptLanguage.Python)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "script_callback_language": "python"})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template = hou.FolderParmTemplate("folder2", "Paths to Cached Matrices", folder_type=hou.folderType.Simple, default_value=0, ends_tab_group=False)
hou_parm_template.setTags({"group_type": "simple"})
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.StringParmTemplate("path_laplacian", "DVEC Laplacian", 1, default_value=(["../vdec_laplacian1/"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.NodeReference, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "oprelative": "."})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.StringParmTemplate("path_sharp", "DVEC Sharp Matrix", 1, default_value=(["../vdec_sharp_matrix1/"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.NodeReference, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "oprelative": "."})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
# Code for parameter template
hou_parm_template2 = hou.StringParmTemplate("path_system_matrix", "MINCURR System Matrix", 1, default_value=(["../mincurr_system_matrix1/"]), naming_scheme=hou.parmNamingScheme.Base1, string_type=hou.stringParmType.NodeReference, menu_items=([]), menu_labels=([]), icon_names=([]), item_generator_script="", item_generator_script_language=hou.scriptLanguage.Python, menu_type=hou.menuType.Normal)
hou_parm_template2.setTags({"autoscope": "0000000000000000", "oprelative": "."})
hou_parm_template.addParmTemplate(hou_parm_template2)
hou_parm_template_group.append(hou_parm_template)
hou_node.setParmTemplateGroup(hou_parm_template_group)
# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/label1 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("label1")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("Sub-Network Input #1")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/label2 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("label2")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("Sub-Network Input #2")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/label3 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("label3")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("Sub-Network Input #3")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/label4 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("label4")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("Sub-Network Input #4")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/resimulate parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("resimulate")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("0")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/folder0 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("folder0")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(0)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/tau parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("tau")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(0.040000000000000001)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/c_threshold parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("c_threshold")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(0.5)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/folder1 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("folder1")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(0)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/rhs parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("rhs")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(32)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_eta0 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_eta0")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(2)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_eta parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_eta")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(5)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_phi parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_phi")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(9)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_X parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_X")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(10)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_Xhat parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_Xhat")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(13)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_Xprev parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_Xprev")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(16)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_lambda parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_lambda")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(19)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_lambdahat parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_lambdahat")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(22)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_lambdaprev parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_lambdaprev")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(25)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_Y parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_Y")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(28)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/ind_summand parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("ind_summand")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(31)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/folder2 parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("folder2")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set(0)
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/path_laplacian parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("path_laplacian")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("../vdec_laplacian1/")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/path_sharp parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("path_sharp")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("../vdec_sharp_matrix1/")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


# Code for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver/path_system_matrix parm 
if locals().get("hou_node") is None:
    hou_node = hou.node("/obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver")
hou_parm = hou_node.parm("path_system_matrix")
hou_parm.lock(False)
hou_parm.deleteAllKeyframes()
hou_parm.set("../mincurr_system_matrix1/")
hou_parm.setAutoscope(False)


hou_node.setExpressionLanguage(hou.exprLanguage.Hscript)

# Code to establish connections for /obj/Minimal_Current/mincurr_FFT_solver
hou_node = hou_parent.node("mincurr_FFT_solver")
if hou_parent.node("mincurr_FFT_initialize") is not None:
    hou_node.setInput(0, hou_parent.node("mincurr_FFT_initialize"), 0)
hou_node.setUserData("___Version___", "19.5.465")
if hasattr(hou_node, "syncNodeVersionIfNeeded"):
    hou_node.syncNodeVersionIfNeeded("19.5.465")
```

To address this question, I had to consult information related to Python SOP (surface operators in Houdini), such as: https://github.com/kiryha/Houdini/wiki/python-for-artists#python-integration-basics

Answer (score 2):

[As commented on meta by @adabsurdum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423414/are-questions-about-using-uncommon-software-tools-for-viewing-reading-code-on-to#comment948584_423414), the `.hipnc` file can be opened in a plain-text editor such as vi or emacs. It does have some binary blobs in it, and I *don't know if it will actually be useful as 'source code' to help you understand what the authors are doing*, but it's not hard to examine.

It's similar to what you would see in an uncompressed PDF or PostScript file - basically, graphics primitives expressed in (mostly) plain text.

For example, the first few lines are (copy-pasted from emacs):

```
HouNC^Z1033600baa06089de3b09a7e5953.start^@fplayback -i on -r off -f 1 -e on -h on -t on -a on -k on -s 1
tcur 0
fps 24
tset 0 10
frange 1 240
unitlength 1
unitmass 1
prompt '`strcat(oppwf(), " -> ")`'
HouNC^Z1033600ba606089de3b043eebadb.variables^@set -g ACTIVETAKE = 'Main'
set -g DRIVER = 'mantra_ipr'
set -g DRIVERPATH = '/out/mantra_ipr'
set -g E = '2.7182818284590452354'
set -g EYE = 'stereo'
set -g HIP = '/Users/achern/Documents/MinimalCurrent/supplementary'
set -g HIPFILE = '/Users/achern/Documents/MinimalCurrent/supplementary/mincurr.hipnc'
set -g HIPNAME = 'mincurr'
set -g JOB = '/Users/achern'
set -g PI = '3.1415926535897932384'
set -g POSE = '/Users/achern/Library/Preferences/houdini/16.0/poselib'
set -g _HIP_SAVEPLATFORM = 'macosx10.14-x86_64-clang10.0-targetosx10.12'
set -g _HIP_SAVETIME = 'Wed Apr 28 15:14:19 2021'
set -g _HIP_SAVEVERSION = '18.0.532'
set -g _HIP_SHELFTOOLCOUNT = '14'
set -g status = '0'
```

and lines 26112 and following are:

```
viewroto  -S file -F '' -C '' -a on -o 0 0 -s 1 1 -B 1 -e off image Build.panetab1.world.persp1                    
viewtransform Build.panetab1.world.persp1 version ( 3 )  flag ( Fx )  orthowidth ( 5.22896 )  focal ( 50 )  apertu\
re ( 41.4214 )  window ( 0 1 0 1 )  winroll ( 0 )  clear ( 1 )  nearfar ( 0.135896 6678.76 )  aspect ( 1.33333 )  \
pixelaspect ( 1 )  txyz ( -0.1549 -0.00862012 7.265 )  pxyz ( -0.827671 -1.16344 -0.0768346 )  rotation ( 0.070341\
9 0.709621 -0.701065 1.32842e-07 0.702805 0.711382 0.997524 -0.0500401 0.0494366  )  homedistance ( 8.02968 )  hom\
eadjboxwidth ( 5.22896 )  homeorthowidth ( 5.22896 )  homeradius ( 6.67073 )  homeaxis ( 0 )  homecustom ( 0.70710\
7 -0.353553 0.612372 0 0.866025 0.5 -0.707107 -0.353553 0.612372  )  adjustlimits ( 3 )                            
viewcamera -c '' Build.panetab1.world.persp1                                                                       
vieworthogrid -d off -o 0 0 0 -s 0.2 0.2 -r 5 5 -R 1 Build.panetab1.world.persp1                                   
viewuvgrid -r on -s 0.1 0.1 -P off -S 64 64 -O 0 0 -C on -t on Build.panetab1.world.persp1                         
viewagentopts  -L on -b 0 -d 1 -l 0 -m 4 -p 1000 -w 1 Build.panetab1.world.persp1                                  
viewonionskin  -e on -a 4 -b 4 -i 6 -o 0.5 -A 1 1 1 -B 1 1 1 Build.panetab1.world.persp1                           
viewposteffects  -f off -S on -b 5 -F 1 -c 1 1 1 -d 1e+06 -h 0 -H 100 10 -i 1 -n "" -o 1 -r 0 1000 -s 1 1 -v 0 Bui\
ld.panetab1.world.persp1
```

Comment: The issue is the finla goal is to see how the author's implemented their paper. Trying to fish the actual paper code out of this representation is likely a lot of effort. I assume Houdini has some kind of editor, since the authors claim teh actual source code of their methodexists in houdini.

Comment: I understand. I'm answering your narrow technical question ("how do I look at the contents of a `.hinpc` file?"), not the broader questions ("how do I figure out what the authors are doing? Is the source code *really* in the Houdini file? How do I interpret it?") I see that the authors **say** "All source code are [sic] available online in the form of Houdini files.", and that the `.hinpc` file is the only thing provided on the web page, but beyond that I have no idea ...